# command to view osgi revision in apache-karaf

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

How to view osgi revision and other information in Apache-Karaf. I am using 2.3.10 i couldn't find any such command in CLI. osgi:header and other commands of osgi: displays the bundle related information.

Answer (score 1):

A full list of all commands available can be found [here](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/commands/commands.html), including a description.

But for revision, like it's the 10th update to that bundle, there is no command to show this information.

Comment: It would be nice if we have that.

Comment: For sure it would be nice, we love contribution.